# FTP - открытие файлов на редактирование

Tags: ftp, ftp-сервер

Столкнулся с таким, можно сказать неудобством, настроил FTP-сервер (на базе ОС Windows 7), и потом задумался, пользователи привыкли открывать файлы и редактировать их из общего ресурса.
С FTP такое, на стандартных настройках не срабатывает.
Приходится пользователю делать четыре действия при редактировании файла, а не одно, как хотелось бы. Т.е. Скачать > отредактировать > закачать обратно > удалить скачанный файл. А у неопытных пользователей ещё и выбрать каталог куда скачивать, а позже, ещё и потратить время на поиски скачанного, для удаления после редактирования.
В общем хотел реализовать обмен файлами и редактирование их, на подобии локального ресурса по сети.
Есть ли какая-то возможность реализации моей задумки.
Или FTP-это не тот путь решения данной задачи?
Удалённый рабочий стол не предлагать, так как нужна необходимость и быстрого, удобного скачивания и обмена файлами.
Вот прям-таки, как у ЛВС - полное удобство, но ресурс должен находится вне ЛВС.

Comment: Сервисы, подобные Яндекс.Диску, Google Drive и Mega не решат вашу задачу? Там можно настроить синхронизацию с папкой и для конечного пользователя всё будет выглядеть прозрачно, словно он работает с локальными файлами, а не с облаком.

Comment: @terron, а как же конфиденциальность данных? Хранение документации у сторонних посредников противоречит безопасности данных и теряется понятие коммерческой тайны.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите на программу [WinSCP](https://winscp.net). Сам не пользовался, но, вроде бы, решает большинство поставленных вами задач.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

настроить vpn, работа как по локальной сети. Из бесплатных серверов/клиентов openvpn

Comment: С VPN-сервером столкнулся впервые. Настроил, подключаюсь. Первое - это пропадает интернет у клиента и второе, это если интернет победить, то как открыть ресурсы на сервере?
Не откажусь от мануала, если конечно у вас есть ссылки на настройку под ключ.

Comment: мануала нет, вроде всегда все прозрачно настраивалось. Как может пропасть интернет, ума не приложу. Я брал стандартный конфиг из openvpn правил ключи и все

Comment: единственное что пришло в голову, вы не одну подсеть сделали с основной в клиентских машинах?

Comment: Создал VPN на сервере и создал подключения к нему на клиентах.
Но тут столкнулся с тем, что когда один заходит, второй клиент уже не может. Это ограниченность ОС не серверной версии? (Стоит Win 7-ка 64 бит "Максимальная"). Выхода нет? Т.е. ставить нужно для более чем одного клиента серверную версию ОС?

Comment: не понимаю, не должно быть ограничения. А какой  vpn сервер установлен?

Comment: таки обычный от Windows. Он там (на сервере) просто через создать подключение.
В "сетевых настройках" - "Файл" - "новое входящее подключение" там выбрал пользователей и  "через интернет (другим ПК разрешено подключение к этому ПК через VPN...)".

Comment: тогда это, скорее всего, ограничение местное. Я не пользовался, не знаю. Использую всегда свободную реализацию vpn, openvpn https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html